# Spree installation uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions

Tags: spree

I'm trying to install Spree following their guide here : http://guides.spreecommerce.com/getting_started.html

I'm stuck on a weird problem :

```
    /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/inflector.rb:407: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions (NameError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/core_ext/string.rb:3
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/spree_cmd-1.2.2/lib/spree_cmd/installer.rb:2
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/spree_cmd-1.2.2/lib/spree_cmd.rb:13
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/spree_cmd-1.2.2/bin/spree:2
    from /usr/local/bin/spree:19:
```

I'm using Ubuntu Server 12.04 and Rails 3.2.9.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RyanBigg suggested that was a version problem of rails. The solution was to uninstall the rails version of APT and to install it through gem, while focusing on setting up the **exact version** mentionned in [the spree installation guide](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/getting_started.html) :

```
sudo aptitude remove
gem install rails -v 3.2.3
```

Opposed to what you might think the APT version was "too recent" (3.2.9).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend uninstalling the version of Ruby that was installed using apt-get, and instead install it with [this guide](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/).